# Win10 slow localhost access when network cable unplugged

Tags: networking, apache-http-server, localhost, windows-10-v1607

We have a web application that we deploy on either Win7 and Win10.  The web client connects to apache and to our back-end server over HTTP and HTTPS.  In one of our deployment scenarios, everything is deployed to a single PC (the localhost scenario). One of our testers noticed that on Win10 if he simply unplugs the PC's network cable, the web app is noticeably slower than  when the cable in plugged in -- even though we're not actually going out on the network, we're just connecting to localhost.  On Win7, with the exact same code and configs, the app is noticeably faster.

Does this make any sense to anyone? What would make Win10 slow down, but eventually work,  when trying to access localhost when the network cable in unplugged?

thanks

--

2 additional pieces of information: (a) we have IPv6 disabled.  (b) the speed difference when the network cable in unplugged is about 4 seconds.  If a page would normally take say 1 second to come up; if the cable is unplugged, it will take 5 to come up.  thanks

Comment: Probably one simple answer: DNS. Has Windows had its hosts file to point your local install to "localhost", an IP or a named virtualhost (a domain name)? Addotionally, Windows 10 will look at IPv6 first so if you have a domain name or virtual host you'll need to set the hosts file to also have an IPv6 entry.

Comment: With localhost interface apps talk to each other in same machine, hence the name loopback adapter. You can see that loopback packets with [rawcap](http://www.netresec.com/?page=RawCap). See more at [Wikipedia:localhost](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost).

Comment: Does the problem persist if you access `127.0.0.1` instead of localhost? Is a proxy configured on the machine? Is there any software running on the machine that might intercept and inspect network connections that relies on an Internet connection to work, for example security software that checks URLs against an online database of bad websites?